# youtubeAnalytics.reports.query returns 403 forbidden

Tags: youtube-api

As a **contentOwner**, I'm trying to run a query using the Google API explorer and in return I get 403 forbidden, here are the steps to reproduce the issue:

1. login to google.com with collectivedigitalstudios@gmail.com
2. go to the API explorer and enter the wanted params (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v1/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query?ids=contentOwner%253D%253DCollective&start-date=2013-08-01&end-date=2013-08-02&metrics=views&filters=channel%253D%253DUCYjk_zY-iYR8YNfJmuzd70A&_h=1&)
3. authorize the requested scopes:

   1. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly
   2. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly
4. Execute

here's the complete request/response:

youtubeAnalytics.reports.query executed 14 minutes ago time to execute: 796 ms

**You do not have permission to execute this method.**

**Request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=contentOwner%3D%3DCollective&start-date=2013-08-01&end-date=2013-08-02&metrics=views&filters=channel%3D%3DUCYjk_zY-iYR8YNfJmuzd70A&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Authorization:  Bearer ya29.AHES6ZQM1y53hLCD4uBa5BSjACg1Pr8NK4WmUUm_jyuxKYhVqA
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer
```

**Response**

```
403 Forbidden

- Hide headers -

cache-control:  private, max-age=0
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  118
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Thu, 15 Aug 2013 18:21:38 GMT
expires:  Thu, 15 Aug 2013 18:21:38 GMT
server:  GSE

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

I opened a bug and it was closed as "WorksForMe". well, it doesn't.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are other queries working for you?

Comment: Any query I run on youtubeAnalytics.reports.query returns the same 403 error. When trying the Data API (as apposed to Analytics), I get the results.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3D<YOUR_CHANNEL_ID>&start-date=2013-12-30&end-date=2014-01-05&metrics=views%2Cuniques%2Clikes%2Cdislikes%2Ccomments%2Cshares&dimensions=day&filters=video%3D%3D<YOUR_VIDEO>&sort=-day
```

And add in the scope: **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube**

Comment: I am getting the same issue,Are you guys manage to solve this.